# SQLITE ON UPDATE Actions

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, foreign-keys

Based on the [SQLite foreign key documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html), it should be the way of creating two database, and the field that referencing the parent field will get updated too if  the parent field get updated.

Problem: Once I follow the step below, everything is working fine until the last command
`SELECT * FROM track;` because the result still remain the same like following whereby it should change to the result at shown at the last.

```
  trackid  trackname          trackartist
    -------  -----------------  -----------
    11       That's Amore       1
    12       Christmas Blues    1
    13       My Way             2
```

coding:

```
-- Database schema
CREATE TABLE artist(
  artistid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  artistname  TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE track(
  trackid     INTEGER,
  trackname   TEXT, 
  trackartist INTEGER REFERENCES artist(artistid) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

sqlite> SELECT * FROM artist;
artistid  artistname       
--------  -----------------
1         Dean Martin      
2         Frank Sinatra    

sqlite> SELECT * FROM track;
trackid  trackname          trackartist
-------  -----------------  -----------
11       That's Amore       1
12       Christmas Blues    1
13       My Way             2  

sqlite> -- Update the artistid column of the artist record for "Dean Martin".
sqlite> -- Normally, this would raise a constraint, as it would orphan the two
sqlite> -- dependent records in the track table. However, the ON UPDATE CASCADE clause
sqlite> -- attached to the foreign key definition causes the update to "cascade"
sqlite> -- to the child table, preventing the foreign key constraint violation.
sqlite> UPDATE artist SET artistid = 100 WHERE artistname = 'Dean Martin';

sqlite> SELECT * FROM artist;
artistid  artistname       
--------  -----------------
2         Frank Sinatra    
100       Dean Martin      

sqlite> SELECT * FROM track;
trackid  trackname          trackartist
-------  -----------------  -----------
11       That's Amore       100
12       Christmas Blues    100  
13       My Way             2
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [fine manual](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) with more care:

> **2. Enabling Foreign Key Support**
>   [...]
>   Assuming the library is compiled with foreign key constraints enabled, it must still be enabled by the application at runtime, using the PRAGMA foreign_keys command. For example:
>
> ```
> sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
> ```
>
> Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database connection separately.

So if you say this:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
sqlite> UPDATE artist SET artistid = 100 WHERE artistname = 'Dean Martin';
```

then you'll see the 100s in `track` that you're expecting. Of course that assumes that your SQLite was compiled with FK support.